# echo html and wordpress php variable in string

Tags: php, string, wordpress, echo

I am trying to echo html and php in a string but I get a syntax error with the code below.

```
                        $post_title .= '

                    <div id="show_neil" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_neil">'.
                    '<h4 class="name">'.

                    '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/team/neil.png">'.

                    .get_the_title($post_id).

                    '</h4>'.
                    '</div>

                    ';
```

How do I echo this?

Comment: First, missing semicolon (`;`) at the end of that (which shouldn't bother as long as there is nothing after that, but I suspect that there is more code after this). Second, what does bloginfo return? Third: what syntax error is it throwing?

Comment: bloginfo returns a url. at the end is suppose to be a '.' i've edited above...

Comment: i've updated post and added more code

Comment: Yes, the error is the dot (`.`) (after seeing your edit) after `'/img/team/neil.png">'`. Just remove it and you will be done. In a nutshell, replace `'<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/team/neil.png">'.` with `'<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/team/neil.png">'`. Besides, you should start to find different ways to concatenate strings. PHP offers tons of ways to concatenate elements and the one you're using is odd and hard to read and mantain.

Comment: You should NOT edit your question so radically as to change the entire code and invalidate any existing answers.

Comment: @papirtiger: He should have posted the whole code at the very beginning, because there is a syntax error in the line he had posted, but we couldn't know what syntax error was until he posted the entire code. Apart from get_bloginfo and bloginfo, the syntax error was not thrown because of that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` instead of `bloginfo('template_directory')`.

Comment: A good answer should contain an explanation why he should use `get_bloginfo`.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my answer. Hope it is clear to you now.